# Firebase functions Error: Cannot find module 'diagnostics'

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I keep seeing this error when I run `firebase deploy --only functions` in my functions directory. I get this:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'diagnostics'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Johnson\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\exception-handler.js
- C:\Users\Johnson\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js
- C:\Users\Johnson\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\create-logger.js
- C:\Users\Johnson\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\lib\winston.js
- C:\Users\Johnson\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\logger.js
- C:\Users\Johnson\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\Johnson\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.1\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\bin\firebase.js
```

Here's the content of my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.1",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.0.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "node-mailjet": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I recently (couple weeks ago) updated my functions directory from Node 8 to Node 10, not sure if that is related to this issue. I've tried deleting `node_modules` folder and also `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`. I've also tried running `npm install -g firebase-tools` and then `firebase deploy --only functions`, but error still persists. Please, what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have sorted this out. I simply uninstalled firebase-tools globally from npm and reinstalled. The issue was probably a side-effect of running Windows restore on my PC (Thank you Windows!)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution that works for many of these node/npm problems. First, install yarn using the following command:
npm install -g yarn

Then use yarn to install all the node modules for your project example:

yarn add your_node_module

or

yarn add global your_node_modue  (for global installation)

if for example you want to use firebase commands, and it gives an error or says "command not found", then do this:

yarn firebase init

yarn firebase deploy

etc...